# How would i make a button to switch where points go in a counter?

Tags: java, android, button, buttonclick

I am currently a high school student who decided to try and take up Android dev for fun, but I am stumped. I have an image button for blue team and for red team. The score goes up automatically for blue team. What i dont know how to do is when you hit the red button, the image buttons make the red teams score go up and vice versa.

Here is my java code 
    package com.example.puremmacompetitionjiujitsuscorer;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int blueScore = 0;
private int redScore = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageButton sweep = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    final ImageButton pass = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
    final ImageButton mount = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    final ImageButton backMount = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    final ImageButton kneeOnBelly = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    final ImageButton takeDown = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    final TextView blueScoreCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blueScore1);   
        takeDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                blueScore += 2;
                blueScoreCount.setText("" + blueScore);

                }
            });

        sweep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View w) {
                blueScore += 2;
                blueScoreCount.setText("" + blueScore);
            }
        });

        pass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View q){
                blueScore += 3;
                blueScoreCount.setText("" + blueScore);
            }
        });

        mount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View t){
                blueScore += 4;
                blueScoreCount.setText("" + blueScore);
            }
        });

        backMount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View s){
                blueScore += 4;
                blueScoreCount.setText("" + blueScore);
            }
        });

        kneeOnBelly.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View g){
                blueScore += 2;
                blueScoreCount.setText("" + blueScore);
            }
        });
        };



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
        }
```

Here is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/myLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/purebig" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/redScore1"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/hint"
android:maxLength="2"
android:textIsSelectable="false" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/stop" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:src="@drawable/play"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/kneeonbelly"
    android:onClick="addTwo" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:src="@drawable/backmount"
    android:onClick="addFour" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/mount"
    android:onClick="addFour" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/pass"
    android:onClick="addThree" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:src="@drawable/takedown"
    android:onClick="addTwo" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:src="@drawable/sweep"
    android:onClick="addTwo" />

 <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton9"
     android:src="@drawable/red" />

 <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1"
     android:src="@drawable/blue" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/blueScore1"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:ems="10"
     android:hint="@string/hint"
     android:maxLength="2" 
     android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

     <requestFocus />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's wrong with how you are doing it now with everything else? Add it to the score in the `Button`s `onClick()`

Comment: well i want to make it so when i hit the red button, then when i hit the score buttons, they go to the red score.

Comment: I think I understand, check my answer. Let me know if that is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I possibly understand you. If I do, you can use a flag to see which `Button` was pressed. So the flow would be like

Red button pressed -> flag = red -> Score Button pressed -> red score += score

In code it would be like

```
String flag = "";
public void onRedBtnClick(View v)
{
    flag = "red";
}
public void scoreBtnClick(View v)
{
    if (!flag.equals(""));
    {
         if ("red".equals(flag))
         {
               redScore += score;
         }
         if ("blue".equals(flag))
         {
               blueScore += score;
         }
}
```

This is obviously done really quick and you will have to adjust your variables to your needs. But if I understand what you want then this would give you the basic logic

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I don't seem to understand what this does

Comment: What do you want it to do? Did you follow the logic of it and does any of it make sense?

Comment: it makes sense, i just dont understand where exactly this snippet would go. I also get the following errors Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete BlockStatements
 - flag cannot be resolved

Comment: This snippet could go basically anywhere. It wasn't made to be copied/pasted but to show you how the logic would work and basic syntax. They are just button click functions. I have fixed the error in my answer that was missing a ")". I don't want to come off rude but if you didn't see why it was missing after seeing the error then you really need to learn Java before attempting an Android app

Comment: You arent coming across as rude at all! I perfectly agree with you, I'm using this as a way to strengthen my Java. Would you be able to explain flags? But thank you for all of your help!

Comment: OH MY GOD I FEEL SO STUPID. IT FINALLY JUST CLICKED, THANK YOU SIR

Comment: A flag is just a basic term for something to tell something else what is going on. A green flag in racing means go, a checkered flag means your done...I can't believe you just made me use a NASCAR term, I don't even like racing. Ha!